# UWP (C#) Register Background Tasks Pre-App Launch

Tags: c#, uwp, background-task

I have a UWP app that registers background tasks to update a Live Tile.  These are working fine.

I have provisioned the package, and the icon is pinned to Start Menu, but, the background tasks don't register until a user has launched the app once.

Is there a way to automatically register these?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can do it [during the application Prelaunch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-app-prelaunch), no - there is no way to explicitly run an arbitrary chunk of code after an installation via the Store.

Comment: Also pre-launch is not guaranteed to ever be run for a given app.

Comment: That didn't seem to do it for me.  I know it is a dirty hack, but this is a LoB app, and I can control it end to end, so I registered the app as a URI handler, and have that call the functions to register the background tasks then exit.  It flashes the window briefly, but we're doing a bunch of other stuff on first login, so it doesn't seem too terrible.

Comment: If you're in an enterprise environment, you can probably arrange for a powershell script to launch the app after you install it.